# Use Gnome dash-to-dock without autohide

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, autohide, dash-to-dock

I recently installed the 'dash-to-dock' extension for Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04 as I liked the way it looked as opposed to the default dock.

I liked the extension although I wasn't keen on the auto-hide feature as I like to see the dock at all times so I can see what applications I have open and badge icons for messages, etc. I turned off the autohide feature. Although when I did that I got this:

[image: screenshot of autohide disabled]

The dock pushed up the window instead of overlaying it as I expected it would and how it appeared when autohide was enabled. I checked in settings but I wasn't able to find anything to change this. I also tried the 'dash-to-pannel' extension but it didn't acheive what I wanted. There didn't seem to be much about this online either.

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this either by using this extension or another one or is it just not possible in Gnome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see the dock at all times..
here is the workaround..

Don't turnoff the Auto-hide feature as you mentioned in the Question.

locate the `dash-to-dock extension` direcotry, it could be either in `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` or `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

open the file `intellihide.js`, in my case it is

```
$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/intellihide.js
```

at line number 105 (`this._isEnabled = true;`) # Change the value to `false`

```
enable: function() {
    this._isEnabled = false;
    this._status = OverlapStatus.UNDEFINED;
    global.get_window_actors().forEach(function(wa) {
        this._addWindowSignals(wa);
    }, this);
    this._doCheckOverlap();
},
```

save the file & close.
refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 type r and press Enter

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]