# Set dock to be always visible

Tags: gnome, dash-to-dock

I am trying to have dash to dock always visible on top of other windows. I almost managed to achieve it with these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hide-delay 9999999
```

achieved result:

[image: screenshot]

Only issue I am having now is that every time i press super and than go back to the desktop the dock hides. Is there a possibility to make it always visible and on top of each window? Please I am desperate for help :D

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1204214/739431 is this helpful?

Comment: yes thank you it was:
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/intellihide.js  line 102

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using Gnome Extension. Follow these steps:

1. Open Extensions and go "Built-In" section and turn on Ubuntu Dock.
2. Go to it's settings in "Position and size" section find "Intelligent auto-hide " turn it on and go to settings.
3. And now copy using the following things in the image:

[Intelligent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaF4J.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey9ZX.png)